# How can calculate distance in feet between two places?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, math

I am working in php. I designed a function which calculates the distance between two places.

Please tell me how to do this if I want to calculate the distance in feet. i want to know that should i change the formula.. dont show your knowledge by downvoting me...

Comment: This entire question boils down to "how many feet in a mile?". The answer, for reference, is that 1 mile = 5280 feet.

Comment: Indeed, this has nothing to do with PHP or MySQL at all. Learn to divide and conquer your software problems!

Comment: should i change the formula if i want to get value in feet ? the person who downvoted me really a bad person.

Comment: Note that your answer may not be accurate to the precision of feet.  You assume that your latitude and longitude values are measured on a spherical Earth with a fixed radius, while real latitude and longitude values are usually measured on a [geodetic datum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datum_(geodesy)).  The same latitude and longitude, represented on a spherical and an oblate Earth shape, can describe points more than a mile apart (e.g. over North America).  You probably want to use [Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae) instead.

Comment: @Tomalak - actually, while divide and conquer may be a valid approach, on this problem it is really one of multiply and conquer, that is, multiply by 5280.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the distance in miles, all you have to know is the conversion from miles to feet:

```
1 mile == 5,280 feet
```

Are the calculations you posted incorrect in some way?

http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=convert+miles+to+feet

Answer (score 2):

1 Mile = 5280 Feet

So multiply your miles by 5280 feet.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you just multiply your miles answer by 5280?

http://www.asknumbers.com/MilesToFeetConversion.aspx